# Sound detector using OpAmp

Tags: operational-amplifier, sensor, esp8266

I'm trying to create sound detector to use with ESP12F you can see schematic below. I've made this on breadboard, but can't make it work stable. So i want to know how should I choose R1 and R2 values or should I use another design?
[image]

UPD. "Can't make work stable" means device either too senstive or not detecting sounds at all
I'm using HMO1003A so i can't find suitable datasheet :(

P.S. I'm not native english speaker so sorry for my english.

Comment: Welcome to EE.SE. (1) "*... but can't make it work stable.*" What does this mean? What did you expect? What actually happens? (2) What is the mic part number and link to datasheet. Please put all the relevant information into your question.

Comment: Your English is good. There are many English speakers on this site that are not as good as you. (1) Can you measure the voltage on the bottom of R1? What is it? (2) Are you using a single-turn potentiometer (or 10-turn)?

Comment: (1) I got 60mV (R1 = 1kOm) it's bad, isn't? (2) single-turn up to 10kOm.

Comment: Questions are "Solved" when you accept an answer. This is not a forum.

Comment: @oleeq2: Regarding your "Solved" in the title: if you go back to the main page you can see the number of answers to each question. Those on a green background have an accepted answer and so are "solved". That's why pipe undid your good citizen action!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The circuit you are working with is not very good.

- The microphone only gives out a few mV AC on top of the 60 mV DC you measured.
- That means you have to adjust R2 very precisely. If it is a single-turn potentiometer on a 3.3 V supply then you will be at \$ \frac {60m}{3.3} = 1.8\% \$ from the end of the potentiometer. This will be very difficult to adjust as you found out.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fSPSpw.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

*Figure 1. The first improvements.*

- It seems that 0 - 120 mV would be enough variation on the potentiometer to make it easier to adjust. This is a ratio of about \$ \frac {3.3}{0.12} = \frac {1}{27.5} \$ of the full scale. Add in R3 and make it about 27 x 10k = 270k. That might be enough to allow you to use the circuit. (You can make R4 a short-circuit, 0 Ω.)

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fLdlOp.png)</sup>

*Figure 2. Second improvement. Apply some feedback to the op-amp.*

In your circuit you are using an op-amp as a comparitor. Op-amps are not well-suited for that application because on some the output "latches" or gets stuck for a short time if it is driven into "saturation" at V+ or V-. A comparitor is usually better.

We may be able to help by adding a little feedback. R5 and R6 set the gain at \$ - \frac{R6}{R5} \$ which is about -50 in this case. That means that a 10 mV swing in input voltage will result in a 0.5 V swing in output. This too should help your sensitivity.

Don't forget to add a decoupling capacitor to the op-amp V+ to ground close by.

---

As I said at the start, this is not a good circuit but if you try out the steps above to see if you can improve it (or make it less bad!) you will learn some useful theory.

Answer (score 1):

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2frJSeK.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Maybe something like this to detect a noise burst and produce a +ve pulse out

Answer (score 0):

Without feedback any opamp is likely to be unstable. Also, the use of a 3.3V supply is suspicious with a LM358.

You need to specify more parameters - what output do you need? What trigger level?
What supply voltage?

Comment: I want to connect it direct to ESP12 pin, i need digital signal on that pin, supply voltage is 3.3v so low logic level is -0.3v...0.825v and high 2.4v...3.6v

Comment: Go read application notes on how to interface to 3.3V logic and how to detect sound with 0 to 3.3V logic output.  LM358 is a very bad idea. Then ask a better question.

Comment: @TonyStewart.EEsince'75 Could you give me link where i should read about how detect sound? What i should better use instead of LM358?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the assembled module. [Example1](https://robotdyn.com/catalog/sound_sens/sound_detector_/). [Example2](https://www.sparkfun.com/products/12642).

Or repeat the scheme on which they are assembled.

[image]

Comment: Unfortunately, i can't use module, because there is no space in package, but i will try repeat you scheme, thank you